# Why are two usernames being appended to list instead of one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, automation, autocomplete

There is an issue with the list logic i believe where my code generates a random username and password and then appends them to seperate usernames and passwords list, however, when i print out this list the code seems to either populate two indexes with the same username, or alternate between one and two of the same username, however, the passwords list seems to be formatted correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried creating a while loop to check if the username is already in the list, however, this just seemed to create a never ending while loop even if the username was unique. I was originally using basic file io logic to write to the file, but I switched to pandas which led to me catching the issue in the first place. I also tried to see if chat gpt had any solutions, but the model said my code seemed to be correct (although i took that with a grain of salt).

```
usernames = []
passwords = []
emails = []
email_names = ['alpha',
                'omega',
                'ruby',
                'sapphire',
                'omegraruby',
                'alphasaphhire',
                'artreus',
                'kratos',
                'leai']


def create_acc():
    
    user_input = int(input('Enter the number of accounts you would like to create: '))
    for i in range(user_input):

        time_stamp = time.time()
        url = 'https://www.reddit.com/account/register/'
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()

        email_name = random.choice(email_names)
        username = generate_username(name_of_user = email_name)
        password = pw_gen()
        usernames.append(username)
        passwords.append(password)
        print(usernames)
        print(username)
        
        #username index 0 matches with password index 0
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'regEmail')))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'regEmail')))
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))

        submit_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))

        email_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
        time.sleep(1)
        email_field.send_keys(rand_email())
        time.sleep(5)
        submit_btn.click()

        user_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'username')))

        pswd_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password')))

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))
        signup_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button')))

        time.sleep(1)
        user_field.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(1)
        pswd_field.send_keys(password)
        
    print('Account creation complete')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there could be an issue with the list logic in your code. The code generates a random username and password and then appends them to separate usernames and passwords lists. However, when you print out the usernames list, the code seems to either populate two indexes with the same username or alternate between one and two of the same username, while the passwords list seems to be formatted correctly